# What does [keyof T] mean after the closing brace in type definition?

Tags: typescript

Looking at the Typescript documentation at this URL
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

```
type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never;
}[keyof T];
```

Can someone explain to me what this [keyof T] after the closing brace mean?
Is there any documentation for this syntax?

Comment: This is called lookup or index access types. Link to newer docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keyof T` means valid keys for the `T` type (you probably knew that). When you have `[x]` after an interface or union type, it picks the type of the property/member with the name `x`. For example ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwChkzk4AuZEAVywCNoBuU8h6gZzClAHNWAX2JgAnjhSoAjMgC8aTLgIBtAERxVAXVYB6AFQjxkmfLqMWxPTuJA)):

```typescript
interface Example {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}
type E1 = Example["a"];
/*
type E1 = number;
*/
```

As far as I know, these "lookup types" are only documented in the TypeScript 2.1 release notes [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html):

> **`keyof` and Lookup Types**
> In JavaScript it is fairly common to have APIs that expect property names as parameters, but so far it hasn’t been possible to express the type relationships that occur in those APIs.
>
> Enter Index Type Query or `keyof`; An indexed type query `keyof T` yields the type of permitted property names for T. A `keyof T` type is considered a subtype of string.
>
> Example
>
> ```typescript
> interface Person {
>   name: string;
>   age: number;
>   location: string;
> }
>
> type K1 = keyof Person; // "name" | "age" | "location"
> type K2 = keyof Person[]; // "length" | "push" | "pop" | "concat" | ...
> type K3 = keyof { [x: string]: Person }; // string
> ```
>
> The dual of this is indexed access types, also called lookup types. Syntactically, they look exactly like an element access, but are written as types:
>
> Example
>
> ```typescript
> type P1 = Person["name"]; // string
> type P2 = Person["name" | "age"]; // string | number
> type P3 = string["charAt"]; // (pos: number) => string
> type P4 = string[]["push"]; // (...items: string[]) => number
> type P5 = string[][0]; // string
> ```
>
> You can use this pattern with other parts of the type system to get type-safe lookups.
>
> ```typescript
> function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
>   return obj[key]; // Inferred type is T[K]
> }
>
> function setProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K, value: T[K]) {
>   obj[key] = value;
> }
>
> let x = { foo: 10, bar: "hello!" };
>
> let foo = getProperty(x, "foo"); // number
> let bar = getProperty(x, "bar"); // string
>
> let oops = getProperty(x, "wargarbl"); // Error! "wargarbl" is not "foo" | "bar"
>
> setProperty(x, "foo", "string"); // Error!, string expected number
> ```

The main part of `FunctionPropertyNames<T>` produces an interface with `never`-typed members for all the properties of `T` that aren't function-typed, and the original member type for those that are. For instance, as shown in the example, if you do this:

```typescript
interface Part {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  subparts: Part[];
  updatePart(newName: string): void;
}

type T1 = FunctionPropertyNames<Part>;
```

`T1` ends up being `"updatePart"` because that's the only key of `T` (`Part`) that has a function type. *Without* the `[keyof T]` part, you'd get the interface with the `never` members instead ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEAUBO7I6gByAhgLYQDOAPACoB8UAvFAN4BQUUA2gNJSoEUANYQQ6AGZRaAXQBc0vjKgQAHsAgIAJpViIUGIQH4o-BQggA3CDgDc7AL7dR4qbPuhIUAKKryYABsIOkYWDi4+ASEXSWl5RV5lNQ1tXXhkNEwoEzMoC2s7RwB6ACooACUIMnRrLR4Yt2UACxsIEqL7dkENHAkSJGgsEkI2TgEtczgyACMbey4EcggFSmAcQQBzeahKOGmwYeBKBSHCbhltuDAtEg1T4AAKCwB3UgoVtc2ASgVLdFQtPYHOx2J5oLQAIzMPQZQy4fA2YhLGj3ej2Uqg8DgqEsABEVxud0OuPY7UxXm8OJ8fjIgWCqPRJXJ0Ep0PCXHG5isczGCyWXIK2y4u32h2OeW5hQ5UAJtwg9wU+OucvuuKBpKK7CAA)):

```typescript
type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never;
}[keyof T];
type Example<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never;
}/* Same as above, but without [keyof T] here*/;

interface Part {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  subparts: Part[];
  updatePart(newName: string): void;
}

type T1 = FunctionPropertyNames<Part>;
/*
type T1 = "updatePart"
*/
type E1 = Example<Part>;
/*
type E1 = {
    id: never;
    name: never;
    subparts: never;
    updatePart: "updatePart";
}
*/
```

It's the `[keyof T]` part that makes `FunctionPropertyNames` provide the *names* of the function-typed properties, rather than the function-typed properties themselves (and `never`-typed ones).

Answer (score 2):

That's called a "lookup type".

1. `keyof X` returns all keys of a type
2. if

```
    interface a {
       foo: never
       bar: string
       baz: number
    }
```

then `type not_here = a['foo']` will be `never`

but lookup types also support passing `keyof Something` in, so

`a[keyof a]` would be the union of all types of `a`s keys/properties, which is `never | string | number`. Though `never` has no meaning in there so TS automatically ignores it, resulting in `string | number`.

(you can of course do `a[keyof b]`, there's no restriction here)

I find that the best way to figure out complex types like this one is to decompose them in steps like I did [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAkgZzMg3gKGf5OALmQylAHM8CAjEgCgEpkBeAPmQDcB7YAE2r4EDZuy68BAXxw4wATwAOKACoB9AIIAeZRxbZqAbQDSyUMgDWEOdxjJlAXRLLj9nJIDcM%20UruqAQtq6%20vjGpiAWVjZ2jnYuyBAAHpAgfGjIAGIAriAIYMDc4QD8yCYkIBCc0J4eXooqqgDCgazByKFmlta2Dk5xicmpGdm5%20UUlyGUVVW4GnVEOnrJ1hC1qWuhgbEs%20NKv%20mhtb3igIe02HQA):

```
interface test {
    a: string
    b: () => void
    c: () => void
}

type T_A<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]
};

type T_B<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never;
};

type T_C<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type a = T_A<test>
type b = T_B<test>
type c = T_C<test>
```

With this you can see the individual steps taken to obtain the desired result, which is "the union of keys which are of type Function".

Comment: I understand what keyof T means but I don't understand why there is a [keyof T] after the closing brace at the end of this type. What is the purpose of it?

Comment: @Dmitri I explained that in my answer, the part starting with "but lookup types also support passing keyof Something in"

Answer (score 1):

This [keyof T] represents any attribute within T.

To better understand, take the following:

```
type AB = {
  aa: number,
  ab: () => number,
  cd: () => number,
  ef: () => number
}

type FunctionPropertyKeyToNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never;
}

/* The only possible value for this  example will be { aa: never, ab: 'ab', cd: 'cd', ef: 'ef' } */
const example: FunctionPropertyKeyToNames<AB> =
```

Now, using [keyof T] we'd get only the values, 
In theory `never, 'ab', 'cd', 'ef'`, but as Typescript won't resolve `never` as a value for you 
You'd end up only with `'ab', 'cd', 'ef'`

Answer (score 0):

In a short, if there is no *[keyof T]*, it would return an object. However, If there is a *[keyof T]*, it would return the key of the object before.